# MS SQL: Use a stored procedures result set in another query?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure I don't want to modify. It's rather large and complex, and I don't want to add any more confusion to it.

So what I would like to do is have another store procedure that calls on the big one, and uses the result set to perform further selects / joins etc.

Comment: The problem now is that I'm getting a nested error...

Answer (score 2):

You can insert procedure's result set into table. Like this:

```
create procedure test
as
begin

 select 1

end

go

declare @t table
(
 id int
)

insert into @t
exec test

select * from @t -- returns one row
```

Comment: I figured I would have to do that, but thought there might be anther way. Thanks for the timing reply.

Comment: I don't think there is any other way to capture result set from the procedure.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a user-defined function instead:

```
create function table_func
()
returns table
as
    return
    (
            select top 10 * 
            from master..msreplication_options  
         )
```

Then, to get your result set

```
select * from table_func()
```

If you still need to call this as a stored proc in other places, create a stored proc that wraps the user-defined function:

```
create procedure test_proc
as
    select * from test_func();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a user defined function which call the stored procedure you have and use it in other queries.